# Advice on simple efficient way to store web form data when no db/auth required

Tags: php, xml, database-design, data-structures

I have a situation where I need to provide an efficient way to process and store comments submitted via a web form. I would normally use PHP and either MySQL or XML to store the data, but this is slightly different in that this web form will only be temporarily available in a closed LAN environment, and all i need to do is process the form data and store it a format which can be accessed by another application on the LAN (Adobe Director). Each request made by the Director app should pop the stack of data. I'm wondering how best to store the data for this type of situation as it's not something I would normally do. I'm thinking possibly storing the data in an XML file, but any advice would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will depend upon the data structure and the types of possible queries on the data. If you need the data as a single unit (without any specific query inside) and you don't have to open the meta data, you might even think of some binary serialization. If the data need to be highly interoperable, XML will be a good choice.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Kangkan. The Director app will be periodically requesting data from the local web server - the user submitted data is simply two textfields and a timestamp, but there may need to be some interoperability as each request for the data should also archive/delete the data so that it is not retrieved on the next request - so maybe XML is the best option here. Either that or Director handles the distinction between archived/new data - I'll need to check what options there are at that end